# How to delete HTML table row

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am creating an HTML table row by clicking `ADD` using Vue.js. For each row I have a `delete button` on click I want to delete the current row.

The issue is `tbody` is defined in other component and `thead` is in other component.

I know how to delete

```js
Vue.component("form-row", {
  template: "#row-template",
  props: {
    itemname: String,
    quantity: Number,
    sellingprice: Number,
    amount: Number
  },
  methods: {
    delete() {
      alert("tedt")
    }
  },
  computed: {
    quantitySynced: {
      get() {
        return this.quantity;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:quantity", +v);
      }
    },
    sellingpriceSynced: {
      get() {
        return this.sellingprice;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:sellingprice", +v);
      }
    },
    amountSynced() {
      this.$emit("update:amount", parseFloat(this.quantity) * parseFloat(this.sellingprice));
      return this.amount
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      this.tableDatas.push({
        itemname: "item",
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        amount: 55
      });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculate() {
      return (
        this.tableDatas.reduce((total, {
          amount
        }) => total + amount, 0) || 0
      );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <form-row v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" v-bind.sync="row"></form-row>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled :value="calculate">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="itemname" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="quantitySynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="sellingpriceSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" :value="amountSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

How can I do this, for deleting I know I can do like this

```
    delete(index) {
  console.log("Removing", index);
  this.tableDatas.splice(index, 1);
}
```

But `tableDatas` is defined in different component.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59539757/how-to-delete-html-table-row#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply `$emit()` the intent of deleting an item and attach appropriate handler for it.

**Child**

```html
<button @click="$emit('delete')">Delete</button>
```

**Parent**

```html
<form-row 
  v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" 
  v-bind.sync="row" 
  @delete="btnOnDelete(key)">
</form-row>
```

```js
{
  methods: {
    btnOnDelete(key) {
      this.tableDatas.splice(key, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
Vue.component("form-row", {
  template: "#row-template",
  props: {
    itemname: String,
    quantity: Number,
    sellingprice: Number,
    amount: Number
  },
  computed: {
    quantitySynced: {
      get() {
        return this.quantity;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:quantity", +v);
      }
    },
    sellingpriceSynced: {
      get() {
        return this.sellingprice;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:sellingprice", +v);
      }
    },
    amountSynced() {
      this.$emit("update:amount", parseFloat(this.quantity) * parseFloat(this.sellingprice));
      return this.amount
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      this.tableDatas.push({
        itemname: "item",
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        amount: 55
      });
    },
    btnOnDelete(key) {
      this.tableDatas.splice(key, 1);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculate() {
      return (
        this.tableDatas.reduce((total, {
          amount
        }) => total + amount, 0) || 0
      );
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <form-row v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" v-bind.sync="row" @delete="btnOnDelete(key)"></form-row>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled :value="calculate">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="itemname" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="quantitySynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="sellingpriceSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" :value="amountSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button @click="$emit('delete')">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.$parent` to call parent method

**Note:** `delete` is a keyword in javascript so it cant be used as a function name

```js
Vue.component("form-row", {
  template: "#row-template",
  props: {
    index: Number,
    itemname: String,
    quantity: Number,
    sellingprice: Number,
    amount: Number
  },
  methods: {
    deleteRow() {
      this.$parent.deleteRow(this.index)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    quantitySynced: {
      get() {
        return this.quantity;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:quantity", +v);
      }
    },
    sellingpriceSynced: {
      get() {
        return this.sellingprice;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("update:sellingprice", +v);
      }
    },
    amountSynced() {
      this.$emit("update:amount", parseFloat(this.quantity) * parseFloat(this.sellingprice));
      return this.amount
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableDatas: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    btnOnClick(v) {
      this.tableDatas.push({
        index: this.tableDatas.length,
        itemname: "item",
        quantity: 1,
        sellingprice: 55,
        amount: 55
      });
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      console.log("Removing", index);
      this.tableDatas.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculate() {
      return (
        this.tableDatas.reduce((total, {
          amount
        }) => total + amount, 0) || 0
      );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="btnOnClick">Add</button>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered mainTable" id="Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="itemName">Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <form-row v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" v-bind.sync="row"></form-row>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <label>Total Row's Amount</label>
    <input type="text" disabled :value="calculate">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" readonly :value="itemname" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" v-model="quantitySynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step=".5" v-model="sellingpriceSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="1" :value="amountSynced" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button @click="deleteRow">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: While this could work, you are tightly coupling it to a specific `$parent`, and this could be bad if the component is used elsewhere (different structure where the removing handler isn't present). Also, I spotted a bug where the last item can't seem to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

See the code attachment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RPRy.png%60)

> $(document).ready(function () {
>               $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
>                   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
>                   return false;
>               });
>    });`